# CSS styling in GTKSharp

Tags: c#, css, gtk3, gtk#

I'm converting a C/GTK+ GUI application to C# using GTKSharp in VS2017. I've installed this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/GtkSharp/3.1.3 via NuGet.

Here's how I load up the CSS (the application uses a Glade file to define the interface):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program(args);
    }

    public Program(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Init();

        builder = new Builder();
        Gtk.CssProvider provider = new CssProvider();
        builder.AddFromFile("interface.glade");
        provider.LoadFromPath("style.css");
        builder.Autoconnect(this);

        Gtk.Window window = (Gtk.Window)builder.GetObject("start"); 
        Gtk.StyleContext.AddProviderForScreen(Gdk.Screen.Default, provider, 800); // couldn't find the equivalent to GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER so I set the priority to a random number
        window.Show();

        Application.Run();
    }
```

The selector names seem to be different from GTK+. For example,

```
    window {
     ...
    }
```

works in C/GTK+ but not in C#, whereas

```
    GtkWindow {
     ...
    }
```

works in C# but not in C/GTK+. Then there are a few widgets I can't seem to style at all. For example,

```
    button {
     ...
    }
```

works in GTK+ but

```
    GtkButton {
     ...
    }
```

does not work in C#. I couldn't find any documentation regarding how GTK# handles CSS styling so I thought it'd be the same as GTK+. Any pointers?

Comment: The 800 value you are looking for (`GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER`) has an equivalent in GtkSharp: `Gtk.StyleProviderPriority.User`

Answer (score 0):

The GTKSharp seems more like an expected GTK3 behavior.

[Here is the reference manual from developer.gnome.org](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html)

Especially useful should be the `Table 1. Selector syntax` section.

In short the elements are named after the GTK class name: GtkButton, GtkLabel and so on.

For a class list of default [GTK3 widgets check out the docs table of content.](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtkobjects.html).

The GTK button is a container widget that doesn't render background so without seeing the actual CSS properties you try to apply using that selector I can't tell you why it doesn't work but you might need to style its content separately e.g.

```
GtkButton GtkLabel {
    color: lime;
}
```

The selector itself `GtkButton` should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It was a version issue.

Version [3.22](https://github.com/openmedicus/gtk-sharp/releases/tag/gtk-sharp-3.22.6) of GTK# detects the GtkButton selector correctly. I was using GTK 3.14's native libraries. There is one [unlisted NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/gtk-sharp-3-win32/3.22.4) that provides win32 libraries for the 3.22 version. Strangely enough, that version detects the old "button", "window"... instead of the "GtkButton", "GtkWindow"... tags.